# Find and replace texts in Linux

Tags: sed

Can someone tell me the command in Linux to replace the following?

```
ExecStart=/sbin/runuser -l <USER> -c "/usr/bin/new %i"
PIDFile=/home/new/.new/%H %i.pid
```

with

```
ExecStart=/sbin/runuser -l <USER> -c "/usr/bin/vncserver %i"
PIDFile=/home/NUSER/.new/%H %i.pid
```

I am a little bit confused with sed as I don't know how to insert line break while replacing.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -r 's@/bin/new@/bin/vncserver@; s@/home/new@/home/NUSER@' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '$!N;s/^(ExecStart=.*)new(.*\nPIDFile=.*\/)new(.*)/\1vnserver\2NUSER\3/;P;D' file
```

Keep two lines in the pattern space and when the required lines are encountered, replace the two strings.